# Google App Engine › Developing Multilingual Web Applications Using JavaServer Pages Technology

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I have a web page which has 3 different languages, Swedish, English and Russian! In my old java page i set this up with WebTexts_en.properties, WebTexts_sv.properties and WebTexts_ry.properties files together with LangSupport.jsp to chose the Locale for the browser. 
All my jsp pages has UTF-8 encoding so this should be correct as well i think.

Now i have moved my page to Google APP Engine and i wonder if there is anybody who have some input on how to make this here? I have tried to follow my old setup but it seems not to work, my page are there but i have no text what so ever, http://neptune-app-id.appspot.com/
So i wonder if there is anybody who have some input on how google like to set this up? I need help with the whole setup of this, where to place my files, what to include to get this to work, How to setup up my LangSupport file so it choose the right Locale for the browser.

Would also be nice if somebody could show me some documentation for this that i can follow when i set this up. I am quiet a beginner with this but i have most of the files from my old page. Sp i only need to convert all this to work with google app engine instead, please help!!!
Any information would be very helpful since i am stuck right now and cannot move forward with my project.

Answer (score 0):

You have locale and dependent on locale you should take properties from correct property file. You can define you EL function that will have messageId and locale parameters. Depending on locale you can load properties from file you need and depending on messageId you can get message you need.

Put ptoperties files to WEB-INF/ so you can load them with java core Properties.

Thats all.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific! I have my property files in my WEB-IN/ folder already. But where i put my locale and where i find this file?

Comment: I am completely lost here with google. And it was quiet some time ago i had this JSP site. So i need some good help here to be able to make this good and up and running. So please help me if you have time!!!

Comment: You should define locale based on IP address or allow user to set it manually.

Comment: Could you please show me how the code looks for this? Or how i make this file one time?

Comment: I get this error message now when i try to deploy the page.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Session support is not enabled in appengine-web.xml.  To enable sessions, put <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled> in that file.  Without it, getSession() is allowed, but manipulation of sessionattributes is not.

Comment: This is fixed now but there is still something wrong, my page looks like this now, http://neptune-app-id.appspot.com/ My text files are not read properly i think...

Comment: After a few error messages and tweaking with the page it looks like this now, http://neptune-app-id.appspot.com/ In my logs in google app engine i get this messages from my last deploy,

No handlers matched this URL.

No handlers matched this URL.

/ java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.LocalizationContext at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time.

Comment: Anybody who can help me with resource bundle, where to to find or how to make??

Comment: The page do not load my properties files correctly, what am i doing wrong here? http://neptune-app-id.appspot.com/

Comment: I have moved the files to WEB/INF/classes instead and check this out, http://neptune-app-id.appspot.com/ it works. Thank you very much for all your help mate.

-Jesper

Comment: My page works now in English, http://neptune-app-id.appspot.com & http://neptune-app-id.appspot.com/?locale=en_GB but only this language, Swedish and Russian language do not work. If i try to change it stays in English only.
Somebody with an input what is missing here or if i still do something wrong! Please help since i am so close to solve this issue now.

Comment: I have this error message in my console in google app engine;

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.LocalizationContext

Comment: This problem is solved now, thank you all for you great help and advise regarding this.